# How to use Swagger Codegen with .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger-codegen

I am able to integrate the Swagge UI in my web api using Swashbuckle. I also want to explore the swagger codegen feature. Can somebody help in - how I can integrate swagger codegen into my web api project? Or do I need to download any tool? I want to be able it to host the codegen and pass the json/raml form specs to generate client in .net core.

I am not able to find enough docs on above.

**EDIT : I want to know how I can host codegen in my WEBAPI.**

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into the [documentation and support forum](https://swagger.io/forum/)? There might be a 'getting started' guide

Comment: @JamieTaylor I am not able to understand if I need to download the codegen tool or is there any ways that I can integrate it in the code directly. Like we do for swagger ui

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "integrate Swagger Codegen"? 1) Generate client SDKs for your API so you can provide these SDKs to your users. 2) Host codegen in your app similar to what [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) does. 3) Something else?

Comment: @Helen yes I want to host codegen in my app.. I am already hosting Swagger UI but not able to find how I can host codegen

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/33365276/113116 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/39730438/113116

Comment: @Helen - in urls they have mentioned to use https://generator.swagger.io so I would need to send my files to third party sites. Can this generator be hosted in my env?

Answer (score 3):

Now, you can use [Nswag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag). There are several code generator utilities - UI, Console, msbuild.

Answer (score 1):

You should install "`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger`" nuget package by right click your project and click manage nuget packages.

Then you should add these codes into your project startup place eg. `Program.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: That's a fantastically succinct way to describe what needs to be done in order to add Swagger. For a slightly longer form version, I'd recommend [one of my blog posts](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/12/07/giving-dwcheckapi-that-swagger/) (where I take a pre-existing app and add swagger to it, , along with including XML documentation)

Comment: @Metehan this is for Swagger UI. I am able to generate that. I want details about swagger codegen

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding but this is a fairly detailed topic. You can look at blog post who @JamieTaylor pointed above.

Comment: @MetehanSenol have you looked into the [documentation and support forum](https://swagger.io/forum/)? There might be a 'getting started' guide

Comment: @MetehanSenol Thanks anyways!

Comment: I have a very similar question and this answer clearly doesn't cover to OP's question. It's pretty well documented how to add swagger to a dotnet project, but how can we generate a javascript client from that swagger automatically similar to swagger codegen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want to generate C# from the OpenApi specification (your Swagger implementation provides the input) of your API.

To generate code (e.g. C#) from the OpenApi spec file of your API, you can do something like this:

```
java -jar .\openapi-generator-cli-5.0.0-beta3.jar generate -i https://localhost:xxxx/api/v1/swagger.json -g csharp
```

You have to download the OpenApi Generator Jar. Alternatively you can upload your code to a web generator. But I would always run this locally; you never know where your code ends up.

Comment: right language, wrong version.  He is asking about .NET core (1, 2,or 3) or .NET (5 or 6).  Currently, the only backend .NET generators for swaggergen are `csharp` and `csharp-dotnet2`.  `csharp` is for .NET Framework 4.5, and `csharp-dotnet2` is for .NET Framework 2.0.