# No constructor for type SwaggerGenerator can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-3.0

I'm trying to add Swagger to my project. The error received is as follows.

> No constructor for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.

Since I haven't changed anything in Swagger binaries themselves, just installed the packages *Swashbuckle.AspNetCore* and *Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger* (both in version 4.0.1) I'm assuming that it's about the configuration. Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48539782/1525840), I've set up the config shown below.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(_ =>
{
  _.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Version = "v1", Title = "My API" });
});

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(_ => { _.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API docs"); });
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing a package, if one of those I have is the wrong version or if the set config I'm providing isn't sufficient.

Comment: Check documentation here https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah, it was missing the API explorer. that's  a new concept to me as I wasn't using it before (at least explicitly). During my struggle today I've found another manager for [swaggering .NET Core projects - nSwag](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/AspNetCore-Middleware). It's doing the same job as the good old Swashbuckle **but** with the advantage that it's much easier to set up (basic version requires no arguments being passed in). The downside's that it's changing rapidly and a bit hard to find docs on non-obsolete methods as the software matures. But so  is the case with both.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As the asker noted in a comment, what solved this for me was adding in a reference to Api Explorer in `ConfigureServices`.

Specifically the line required was:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddApiExplorer();
```

Comment: Leaving a comment for the next person who has the same problem I had. All my 'other' projects I was copy-pasta-ing from used `.AddMvc()`, which does `.AddApiExplorer()` under the covers. I was trying to add swagger to a new project that only used `.AddMvcCore()` and didn't realise it omits the `.AddApiExplorer()` services.

Comment: This fix also works in .NET Core 3. The migration docs say not to call `services.AddMVC()` (in ConfigureServices), but Swashbuckle seems to need it.

Answer (score 5):

***.Net 7 Updated Solution:***

I know that the answer of (T S Taylor) is correct but for guys who looking for an updated answer in .net 7:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddMvcCore();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register  `services.AddMvc();` in `IServiceCollection`, and configure `app.UseMvc()` in `IApplicationBuilder` in your application's `Startup.cs`